# DOS commands for Epson dot matrix not working

Tags: command-line, printing, disk-operating-system

Our Epson dot matrix printer is not printing on the following DOS command.:

```
Type text.txt>prn
```

But it does print perfectly on:

```
open TEXT.txt>File>Print
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: Wow... dot matrix and DOS... that takes me back. I've never had good experiences with Epson printers though.

Comment: It gives message like--> access is denied(was running on system ADMIN)

Comment: is that DOS command is rite.?? for printing textfile that in c drive.

- c:\>Type one.txt>prn

Answer (score 0):

It worked with this command:

```
Type textfile.txt > lpt3
```

The printer was connected to the `lpt3` port.